# Can we assign an object key to another variable like this?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an Object

```
Object = {'test1':1, 'test2':3, 'test3':2}
```

can I get an output like this.

```
Object = [{"username": "test1", value:1},
          {"username": "test2", value:3},
          {"username": "test3", value:2} 
]
```

Comment: `Object.entries({'test1':1, 'test2':3, 'test3':2}).map(([username, value]) => ({username, value}))`